# Ajax отправка $_FILES + $_POST

Tags: ajax, файлы, post

Используется такой код:

```
<input class="file" id="avatar" name="file" type="file" />
<input class="text" id="username" name="username" type="text" />

function avatar() {
    var file = document.querySelector("#avatar").files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", file);
    alert(fd);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'avatar.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){  
            $("#window_data").html(html);
        } 
    });
}
```

Вопрос, как добавить в данном скрипте еще параллельно отправку пост параметров, значение username к примеру?

Comment: ну так используй например `append` и для параметров

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста на примере, я как не пробовал не работает...

Comment: Файлы же идут POST запросом. Поэтому можно их сразу и добавить `fd.append("key","value");` А на сервере уже берете из $_POST с ключом "key"

Comment: таки `fd.append('username', $('#username').val());` к примеру. А вообще можно и вообще [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) использовать для формы сразу

Answer (score 1):

Передавай в data не только этот объект, но и другие параметры

```
data: {
  fd: fd,
  parametr: value
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, вот такая ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 1):

```
 fd.append("username", $("#username").val());
 fd.append("file", file);
```

Comment: Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: Добавляю: processData: false, contentType: false, на сервере $_FILES + $_POST пустые...